# Amazon S3 / Merge between two buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two buckets `a` and `b`. Bucket `b` contains 80% of the objects in `a`.

I want to copy the remain 20% objects which in `a` into `b`, without downloading the objects to local storage.

I saw the [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), but as I understant, it copy all the objects from `a` to `b`, but as I said - I want that it will copy only the files which exist in `a` but doesn't exists in `b`.

Answer (score 6):

Install aws cli and configure it with access credentials

Make sure both buckets have the same directory structure

[AWS S3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

> The following sync command syncs objects under a specified prefix and
>   bucket to objects under another specified prefix and bucket by copying
>   s3 objects. A s3 object will require copying if the sizes of the two
>   s3 objects differ, the last modified time of the source is newer than
>   the last modified time of the destination, or the s3 object does not
>   exist under the specified bucket and prefix destination. In this
>   example, the user syncs the bucket mybucket2 to the bucket mybucket.
>   The bucket mybucket contains the objects test.txt and test2.txt. The
>   bucket mybucket2 contains no objects:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```

Comment: No, this will sync only files in a that is not in b, just make sure the 2 buckets have the same directory structure, or the sub directory. like s3://<bucket a>/<bucket sub folder>/ s3://<bucket b>/<bucket sub folder>/, the s3 sync command acts similar to rsync

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS SDK and write a php or other supported language script that will make a list of filenames from both buckets, use array_diff to find out the files that are not common, then copy the files from Bucket A to memory then place the file in Bucket B.

This is a good place to start: [https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html)

More in depth on creating arrays of filenames (keys): [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingPHP.html][2]

Some code for retrieving keys

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucket));

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
}
```

[Here describes how to move keys from bucket to bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html)

```
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => $targetKeyname,
    'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
));
```

You are going to want to pull the keys from both buckets, and do an array_diff to get a resulting set of keys that you can then loop through and transfer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is AWS Command Line Interface doesn't support this function? Its really copy object which already exists in the bucket?

Comment: read up on the cp command in aws: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html  it will copy bucket to bucket which might get the job done for you, it will just write all the files. If you want it to exclude files you will probably have to write a shell script to do what I described in php above.